# How to give menu sub menu options

Tags: html, css

Hello I have three buttons which in this three buttons in second one (View Properties By)

button when the user is Hover to it I want to add three more options by hovering the three

options should appear and when the mouse is out so it should back hide.

In here I have used UL and LI for creating these three buttons but now whenever I m

going for creating Hover codes so there is also need of UL and LI so these codes are

creating collision with each other. Below is my code how to add hover code to my CSS that

wont create any collision and achieve sub menus for my view properties by button too

```
CSS code

#header ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 70px 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;   
    width: 605px;
}
#header ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 121px;
}
#header ul li a,
#header ul li a span,
#header ul li a:hover,
#header ul li a:hover span,
#header ul li.selected a,
#header ul li.selected a span {
    background: url(images/menu.jpg);   
}
#header ul li a { 
    background-position: 10px 0; 
    color: #2a4f5e;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
} 
#header ul li a span{ 
    background-position: -70px 0; 
    display: block; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
} 
#header ul li a:hover {
    background-position: -186px -37px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
} 
#header ul li a:hover span { 
    background-position: -70px -37px; 
} 
#header ul li.selected a{ 
    background-position: 10px 36px; 
    color: #fff;
} 
#header ul li.selected a span{ 
    background-position: -70px -74px; 
}
```

---

```
HTML Code

<div id="header">

              <ul>
                  <li class="selected"><a href="Home.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">View Properties By</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../Services.php"><span>Service</span></a></li>   
              </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
Sub Menu CSS Code:

    ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul li{
        float: left;
        width: 190px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 21px;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        color: #333;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul{
        display: none;
    }
    ul li:hover ul{
        display: block; /* display the dropdown */
    }
```

---

```
Sub Menu HTML Code

<ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">View Properties By &#9662;</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">View By Image</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">View By Price</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">View By Zone</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: where is sub menu code and how to want its interface to look atleast share those things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `position` of the sub-menu to `absolute` in order to prevent what you're referring to as a *collision*. Add this to your stylesheet:

```
ul li:hover ul{
        position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I have added this code to my CSS, but now what about sub mens

Comment: You will need to style the sub-menu separately now using CSS like this: `ul li ul { //styles here }`.

Comment: Now you got my question In here my codes are creating collision see my CSS code and my Sub menu CSS code then each and everything  will be clear for you.

Comment: Your HTML structure is incorrect. The sub-menu HTML should be a part of the main `<ul>` inside the `header` div. Here's a simple jsFiddle which I've created for you using basic HTML and CSS which demonstrates the second link having a sub-menu, you can check its HTML structure and CSS and modify your HTML then: http://jsfiddle.net/04gzfrL4/8/

Comment: Its working but has one problem its displaying the sub menus in straight form and has got space between sub menu and button. Is there any way to show you a picture of it in here ?

Comment: Sure, you can upload the image to a website like http://postimage.org and share its link here so i can view it.

Comment: To display each item inside the sub-menu on a different line, you will need to add the following CSS to your stylesheet: `#header ul li ul li { display: block; float: none; }`.

Comment: I have added no effect

Comment: As far as the space between the sub-menu and the button is concerned, there seems to be some padding-top or margin-top set for sub-menu. Please try using this CSS to remove that: `#header ul li ul { padding-top: 0px !important; margin-top: 0px !important; }`

Comment: Try this then: `#header ul li ul li { display: block; float: none; }`

Comment: million thanks it worked. my sub menu has background same as my button is it possible to remove background from sub menu

Comment: You're welcome and yes you can, please try using this CSS: `#header ul li ul li a,
#header ul li ul li a span,
#header ul li ul li a:hover,
#header ul li ul li a:hover span,
#header ul li ul li.selected a,
#header ul li ul li.selected a span {
    background: transparent;   
}`

Answer (score 0):

[click to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/7zyt8bsd/1/)
just modify this class

```
#header ul {
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0 0 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Comment: I have updated my question with sub menu Code. I have code for sub menu but the questions is here that its creating collision as I have mentioned in my question

Comment: can you create jsfiddel for your code @Priyabapat ,here is link to create jsfiddel [link](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I am beginner I dont think so would you please do it for me ?

Comment: ok will create jsfiddel for you,but your code still in complete ,please write code for html sub menu .will create jsfiddel for you  @Priyabapat

Answer (score 0):

First remove in #header ul overflow:hidden, you do not need this.
If you do need a container then wrap your nav in another div.

Over here add position relative as well:

```
#header ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 121px;
    position:relative;
```

}

Then in the sub menu css code add these:

```
ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
}
```

and then this will show the submenu on hover

```
#header ul li:hover ul{
   display:block;
}
```